# Serverless Response Template with Status code

Tags: serverless-framework

I want to create response template for redirect web page using 302 http status. 
I can do it manually with aws lambda user interface but i need to do it with serverless framework version v1.

I tried following code.

```
response:
        headers:
          Content-Type: "'text/html'"
        template: $input.path('$')
        statusCodes:
             201:
                pattern: '' # Default response method
             302:
                pattern: 'http.*'*'
                template:  '$input.path('$')'
                headers:
                     Content-Type: "integration.response.body.errorMessage"
```

But it is not working. How to write response template with status code.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serverless V1 currently not working with status code. But there is a serverless plugin for use status code

1.install plugin

```
npm i serverless-plugin-multiple-responses --save
```

2. Add plugin name in serverless.yml file

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-multiple-responses
```

3. Add this custom code in serverless.yml file ( you can change this code according to your requirement )

```
custom:
   defaultRegion: us-east-1
   region: ${opt:region, self:custom.defaultRegion}
   stage: ${opt:stage, env:USER}
   standardRequest:
      template:
         application/json: ${file(./templates.yml):request}
   standardResponseHeaders:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "'*'"
      'Content-Type': 'integration.response.body.headers.Content-Type'
      'Expires': 'integration.response.body.headers.Expires'
      'Cache-Control': 'integration.response.body.headers.Cache-Control'
      'Pragma': "'no-cache'"
   standardResponseTemplate: "$input.path('$.body')"
   errorResponseHeaders:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "'*'"
      'Expires': "'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT'"
      'Cache-Control': "'no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate'"
      'Pragma': "'no-cache'"
   errorResponseTemplate: "$input.path('$.errorMessage')"
   # Here we are defining what would be under "responses" in your HTTP event
   # if you were not using the custom variables.
   standardResponses:
      200:
         headers: ${self:custom.standardResponseHeaders}
         templates:
            'application/json;charset=UTF-8': ${self:custom.standardResponseTemplate}
      404:
         headers: ${self:custom.errorResponseHeaders}
         templates:
            'application/json;charset=UTF-8': ${self:custom.errorResponseTemplate}
         properties:
            SelectionPattern: '.*\"status\":404.*'
      500:
         headers: ${self:custom.errorResponseHeaders}
         templates:
            'application/json;charset=UTF-8': ${self:custom.errorResponseTemplate}
         properties:
            SelectionPattern: '.*\"status\":500.*'
   redirectResponses:
      # Since we want to return 302 upon a successful completion, we remove the
      # built-in default of 200
      200: false
      302:
         headers:
            Location: "integration.response.body.headers.Location"
         templates:
            'application/json;charset=UTF-8': "$input.path('$.body')"
            'text/html;charset=UTF-8': "$input.path('$.body')"
      404:
         headers: ${self:custom.errorResponseHeaders}
         templates:
            'application/json;charset=UTF-8': "$input.path('$.body')"
            'text/html;charset=UTF-8': "$input.path('$.body')"
         properties:
            SelectionPattern: '.*\"status\":404.*'
      500:
         headers: ${self:custom.errorResponseHeaders}
         templates:
            'application/json;charset=UTF-8': "$input.path('$.body')"
            'text/html;charset=UTF-8': "$input.path('$.body')"
         properties:
            SelectionPattern: '.*\"status\":500.*'
```

4. Add redirect url in your handler file

   module.exports.home = function(event, context) {
      context.succeed({"Location":"https://test.com"})
   }
5. Define function and its responses in serverless.yml file

   responses: ${self:custom.redirectResponses}